# VB6 ADODB Record Set Update

Tags: vb6, ado

So I'm pretty new to Visual Basic and inherited this VB6 code that i need to work on now.  Right now, I'm trying to update a SQL database using an ADODB.RecordSet.  I have a Select SQL statement that pulls the right data from the database into the ADODB.RecordSet, but I'm having problems updating all the rows.  What I am trying to do is to update the same column for each row with the same value.  Right now, its updating a few of the records, but I'm getting an error pop up.  The error I get is:

> Run Time error 3021: Either BOF or EOF
>   is True or the current record has been
>   deleted.  Requested operation requires
>   a current record.

When I click to debug, it takes me to rsUpdate.fields(TargetFieldName) = value

The project itself is huge and too large to post, but the part of the code that I'm working on now is this:

```
If rsUpdate.State = adStateOpen Then
  If rsUpdate.EOF Then
   rsUpdate.Close
   Exit Function
  End If
rsUpdate.MoveFirst
Dim i as Integer
For i = 0 To rsUpdate.recordCount
 rsUpdate.fields(TargetFieldName) = value
 rsUpdate.MoveNext
Next i
On Error GoTo canupdaterecord
rsUpdate.Update
On Error GoTo 0
rsUpdate.Close
End If
Exit function
```

So any help you guys can give me would be greatly appreciated.  Like I said, I'm pretty new to VB and am kind of learning this all as I go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess the problem is an [off-by-one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error:

```
For i = 0 To rsUpdate.recordCount
   rsUpdate.fields(TargetFieldName) = value       
   rsUpdate.MoveNext
Next i
```

If recordcount returns *5*, this loop will make *6* runs: 0,1,2,3,4,5.

I'd write it like this:

```
while not rsUpdate.EOF do
   rsUpdate.fields(TargetFieldName) = value       
   rsUpdate.MoveNext
wend
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
If reUpdate.EOF Then 
    Exit Sub 
End If
```